# how to add a BISM content type

Tags: content-type, business-intelligence

I'm using Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010. I want to create a BI Semantic Model Connection file but no BISM content type exists. According to these technet instructions http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230813.aspx I should be able to find BI Semantic Model Connection File under Business Intelligence Content Types (step 10). But it is not there.
How can I add this content type?

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you unpload it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to matter that the menu option for BI Semantic Model Connections don't exist. The BISM connection file is a simple xml file. I could create one in a text editor, upload it and use it without BISM being available as a Content Type.